# Can we use tf.spectral fourier functions in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Let us start with an input that is a simple time series and try to build an autoencoder that simply fourier transforms then untransforms our data in keras.

If we try to do this:

```
inputs = Input(shape=(MAXLEN,1), name='main_input')
x = tf.spectral.rfft(inputs)
decoded = Lambda(tf.spectral.irfft)(x)
```

Then the third line throws an error when entered:

```
>> ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype complex64 for Tensor with dtype float32
```

You see, the output of tf.spectral.irfft is float32 but it looks like Lambda thinks it is complex64?? (Complex64 is the input x from the previous step)

We can fix that error at model entry time with:

```
inputs = Input(shape=(MAXLEN,1), name='main_input')
x = tf.spectral.rfft(inputs)
decoded = Lambda(tf.cast(tf.spectral.irfft(x),dtype=tf.float32)))
```

This is accepted at input time but then when we try to build the model:

```
autoencoder = Model(inputs, decoded)
```

It generates the error:

```
TypeError: Output tensors to a Model must be Keras tensors. Found: <keras.layers.core.Lambda object at 0x7f24f0f7bbe0>
```

Which I guess is reasonable and was the reason I didn't want to cast it in the first place.

Main question: how do I successfully wrap the tf.spectral.irfft function which outputs float32 ?

More general question for learning:
Let's assume I actually want to do something between the rfft and the irfft, how can I cast those imaginary numbers into absolute values without breaking keras so I can apply various convolutions and the like?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you just need more `Lambda` wrapping (using `tf.keras` since that's what I have installed):

```
import numpy
import tensorflow as tf
K = tf.keras

inputs = K.Input(shape=(10, 8), name='main_input')
x = K.layers.Lambda(tf.spectral.rfft)(inputs)
decoded = K.layers.Lambda(tf.spectral.irfft)(x)
model = K.Model(inputs, decoded)
output = model(tf.ones([10, 8]))
with tf.Session():
  print(output.eval())
```

The output of `irfft` should be real, so probably no need to cast it. But if you do need to cast it (or in general combine operations in a `Lambda` layer), I'd wrap that in a Python lambda: `K.layers.Lambda(lambda v: tf.cast(tf.spectral.whatever(v), tf.float32))`

For example if you know your intermediate values (between `rfft` and `irfft`) will have an imaginary component of zero, you can truncate that off:

```
import numpy
import tensorflow as tf
K = tf.keras

inputs = K.Input(shape=(10, 8), name='main_input')
x = K.layers.Lambda(lambda v: tf.real(tf.spectral.rfft(v)))(inputs)
decoded = K.layers.Lambda(
    lambda v: tf.spectral.irfft(tf.complex(real=v, imag=tf.zeros_like(v))))(x)
model = K.Model(inputs, decoded)
output = model(tf.reshape(tf.range(80, dtype=tf.float32), [10, 8]))
with tf.Session():
  print(output.eval())
```

Note that this isn't true for general sequences, since even real-valued inputs can have imaginary components once transformed. It works for the `tf.ones` input above, but the `tf.range` input gets mangled:

```
[[ 0.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.  4.]
 [ 8. 12. 12. 12. 12. 12. 12. 12.]
 [16. 20. 20. 20. 20. 20. 20. 20.]
 [24. 28. 28. 28. 28. 28. 28. 28.]
 [32. 36. 36. 36. 36. 36. 36. 36.]
 [40. 44. 44. 44. 44. 44. 44. 44.]
 [48. 52. 52. 52. 52. 52. 52. 52.]
 [56. 60. 60. 60. 60. 60. 60. 60.]
 [64. 68. 68. 68. 68. 68. 68. 68.]
 [72. 76. 76. 76. 76. 76. 76. 76.]]
```

(Without the casting we get 0. through 79. reconstructed perfectly)

Comment: I'm marking this as right because I can't deny it runs as shown :) Even if I use tf.keras it won't seem to accept other layers types between the rfft and irfft, though. If I try to put K.layers.Conv1D between those two, for example, even wrapped in a Lambda, I get:  "Value passed to parameter 'input' has DataType complex64 not in list of allowed values:" despite rfft supposedly having real outputs. Do you know how to put convolutions between the rfft and irfft?

Comment: [rfft returns complex64](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/spectral/rfft), so I don't think the dtype is a bug (although maybe convolutions should work on complex numbers?). You can cast/truncate off the complex bit if you know it will be real. I'll add an example of that.

Comment: One option would be to split real/imaginary into channels (`tf.real()` in one channel, `tf.imag()` in the other) for the convolution.

Comment: It's an fft so I would need the magnitude, I'll try that with numerical operations. Thanks!

Comment: This answer combined with: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/42806/27662 by 
@Mark.F helped me.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon this as I was trying to solve the same problem. You can make the transition lossless by wrapping `tf.real` and `tf.imag` into `Lambda` layers (I'm using `stft` because there's no real valued equivalent):

```py
x = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(
    lambda v: tf.signal.stft(
        v,
        frame_length=1024,
        frame_step=256,
        fft_length=1024,
    ), name='gen/FFTLayer')(inputs)
real = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(tf.real)(x)
imag = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(tf.imag)(x)
...
# transform real and imag either separately or by concatenating them in the feature space.
...
x = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.complex(x[0], x[1]))([real, imag])
x = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(
    lambda v: tf.signal.inverse_stft(
        v,
        frame_length=1024,
        frame_step=256,
        fft_length=1024,
    ))(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add more to what's going on above for anyone who gets here from search engines. The following, contributed in [this google group discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/keras-users/lQLAbB6SsI8/C4W-nrgeBgAJ), will run rfft then ifft with convolutions and other layers in between:

```
inputs = Input(shape=(10, 8), name='main_input')
x = Lambda(lambda v: tf.to_float(tf.spectral.rfft(v)))(inputs)
x = Conv1D(filters=5, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = Lambda(lambda v: tf.to_float(tf.spectral.irfft(tf.cast(v, dtype=tf.complex64))))(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
output = Dense(1)(x)
model = Model(inputs, output)
model.summary()
```

It uses the same concepts as Allen's answer but the slight differences allow compatibility with intermediate convolutions.

Comment: `tf.to_float` throws away the imaginary part though?

Comment: Also the rfft is only acting along one axis?