# How to create custom loss function with fft in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, fft, recurrent-neural-network, loss-function

I would like to compute a loss function but I have a problem in using the fft function.
Here the code with numpy:

```
def bidule(y_true, y_pred):
    product = np.fft.fft(y_true) * np.fft.fft( y_pred).conj()
    cc = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.ifft(product))
    return np.argmax(cc.real)
```

I would like to use the Keras backends but when I replace np by K the code don't run.
"module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'fft'"

Answer (score 3):

Please first check the [Keras Backend Documentation](https://keras.io/backend/) to see if there is a `.fft` attribute. There is no `.fft` in the `keras.backend`. However, you can implement one with `tf.signal.fft` using TensorFlow by using a `Lambda` layer with Keras. One example of using `Lambda` with a spectral fourier function in the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50010929/can-we-use-tf-spectral-fourier-functions-in-keras). You can implement yours with the given link.